# Video compression ffmpeg node js in multiple user?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

i have one query i am using ffmpeg packaege in node js to compress video in server side. but my question is when multiple user like 100k upload video in same time so it will work compression then upload part. currently have check 2 or 3 user it is working fine. Thanks Advance

```js
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
const ffmpegInstaller = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg');
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegInstaller.path);
const fs = require('fs');
// var filename = 'videos/big_buck_bunny_480p_10mb.mp4';

(function () {
    
    var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
    function baseName(str) {
        var base = new String(str).substring(str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); 
        if(base.lastIndexOf(".") != -1) {
            base = base.substring(0, base.lastIndexOf("."));
        }     
        return base;
    }

    var args = process.argv.slice(2);
    args.forEach(function (val, index, array) {
        var filename = val;
        var basename = baseName(filename);
        console.log(index + ': Input File ... ' + filename);
        
        ffmpeg(filename)
            // .output(basename + '-720x720_8.mp4')
            // .videoCodec('libx264')
            // //.noAudio()
            // // .aspect("1:1")
            // //.size('720x720')
            // .videoFilters('crop=540:960:540:960')
            // .videoFilters('crop=540:960')
            //.noAudio()
            //.aspect("1:1")
            //.aspectRatio("16:9")
            //.size('720x720')
            //.videoFilters('crop=720:720:580:1000')
            //.addOption('-vf scale=-2:720')
            //.videoFilters('crop=720:720:0:0.21')
            //.addOption('-vf setdar=1')
           //.videoFilters('crop=720:720:-540:960')
            //.preset('divx')

            .output(basename + '-720x720_22.mp4')
            .videoCodec('libx264')
            .addOption('-vf scale=720:-2') // landscap
            //.addOption('-vf scale=-2:720') // portrait

            //.addOption('-vf scale=480:480') // rectangle

           

            .on('error', function(err) {
                console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
                
            })  
            .on('progress', function(progress) { 
                console.log('... frames: ' + progress.frames);
                
            })
            .on('end', function() { 
                console.log('Finished processing'); 
                
            })
            .run();
        
    }); 
    
})();
```

Comment: What? "upload video in same time so it will work compression then upload part." You posted no code and your question is unclear. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i am add code also. my question is this code is working fine but when 100k user same time upload video after comress any issue are facing. need to confirm thanks